# Uses of Dataset.Clone()

Tags: c#, .net, dataset

I've been working with Datasets for the past few days. I wanna knw the uses of Dataset.Clone() method.. I know it is used to get the structure of the dataset. But if someone please explain me which kind of situations demand a **dataset.clone** or a **dataset.copy** method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dataset.clone copies just the structure of dataset (including all the datatables, schemas, relations and constraints.); however it doesn’t copy the data. 
Dataset.copy copies both the dataset structure and the data

situations demand : where you need to transfer data from production to DEv/Test env using .Net ADO, Bulk copy features.

Copy also supports filtering  of data and Data imports.

http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/ViewForum.aspx?ForumId=52327

Answer (score 0):

Use Clone when you only want structure, relations, schema from datatables.
Copy is helpful when you want all schema, structures and data too.